# Search on multiple keywords with tweetsharp

Tags: search, keyword, tweetsharp

I am trying to use Tweetsharp to do a search on twitter for specific keywords but I want to do a search on multiple keywords. The following code works but only for one keyword. Anyone would know how to do an "or" search with tweetsharp?

```
ITwitterLeafNode searchQuery = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
               .Search().Query()
               .ContainingHashTag("heart")
                .Since(sinceID)
               .InLanguage("EN")
               .Take(tweetCount)
               .AsJson();

var results = searchQuery.Request().AsSearchResult();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter's standard search operators seem to work fine with TweetSharp, so you could use the Containing() method instead:

```
var qry = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
                       .Search().Query()
                       .Containing("#heart OR #soul");
```

Note that the "OR" needs to be in capitals.

Comment: Thank you that is actually perfect. I would have loved an answer where I don't have to build the sear4ch string but it works. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Whoops. Looks like we forgot to implement OR. Most people use "Containing" as a rote query expression like Matt has demonstrated. If you want us to add more extensions for boolean operators, let us know by filing a bug.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely do that. We have worked with TweetSharp and really like it, just would like some few extra stuff added.